# What topological spaces can be realized as cell complexes?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homology, cw-complexes

What are the topological spaces can be realized as cell complexes, up to homeomorphism? It seems for instance that all manifolds can be built from cell complexes. It is clear however that one can build more general spaces.

What are the most general spaces that that can be realized, up to homeomorphism as cell complexes (and cannot be built from less general spaces, say simplicial complexes, or polyhedral complexes).

Comment: Up to homeomorphism? Homotopy? This question could use more details...

Comment: Milnor, "On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW-complex": https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-090-02/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4/S0002-9947-1959-0100267-4.pdf

Comment: right, I meant up to homeomorphism. thanks!

Comment: Does "built from cell complexes" mean "are cell complexes"?

Comment: The term "cell complex" has various definitions in the literature so you should give a precise definition. Also, are you sure that you really want a literal answer to your question as stated? Maybe you just want to get some sense of what kinds of "weird" spaces can arise? Also, [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42005) might be helpful to you.